# How to get the URL history after redirecting to different databases?

Tags: xpages

I have a viewPanel on an xpage that links to documents in different databases. I am able to click links to open the documents.After submit the document, i want to redirect the url to the previous viewPanel. Now the problem is that i can't open the viewPanel again and the url history(context.getHistoryUrl) is blank for redirecting to different databases. Any tips on how to get the URL history?

Comment: Are you using context.redirecttopage?

Comment: I use the code: facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("http://www.mydomino.com/mydb.nsf/form_dxm.xsp?documentId=F0A3101A85889FA848257AE1002DCE0D&action=openDocument");

Comment: A I see. See my answer below for a possible solution

Comment: Do you have xsp.redirect=true in your XSP.properties? It is set to this by default, so if you haven't touched it, ignore this comment.

Comment: My problem is that when i use the code:<xp:openPage name="$$PreviousPage"></xp:openPage> in the action button, the page can't return to first xpage in different database. And when i use context.getHistoryUrl to get the history url, the history url array is blank.

Comment: Using facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("mydomino.com/mydb.nsf/….xsp") can redirect to the correct page, but i don't want to use the Static url because the target xpage is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

If you are executing a context.redirecttopage to redirect the user you could change this code so that when you're update has finished the oncomplete is being executed and does a redirect clientside to the correct url. To compute the correct url you can use the code you gave in the answer to my comment.

more info here: http://xpag.es/?192E